# React Native multi line Toast Message

Tags: react-native, toast

Good day SO.

I want to add a multiple-line toast message in React Native APP. However, it is always being cut off on line 2.

Here is my code:

```js
let errString = errors.join("\n");
alerts(errString);

const alerts = (data) => {
  Toast.show({
    topOffset: 100,
    type: "error",
    text1: "ERROR",
    text2: `${data}`,
    visibilityTime: 500,
  });
};
```

On the message it will cut off like this:

```
A long first message
Another long second message...
```

My 3rd message onwards is not displayed.

Comment: Which `Toast` library are you using...Maybe its their design not to show more than two lines. BTW Toast are to show warning, success messages etc. I would suggest.. Don't use them to show long texts

Comment: react-native-toast-message.
I can see the node_module it is limiting the numberofLines. Now, I need to make it dynamic to handle multiple lines

Answer (score 6):

Pass these config in your toast config:

```js
import Toast, {BaseToast, ErrorToast} from 'react-native-toast-message';

const toastConfig = {
  success: (props) => (
    <BaseToast
      {...props}
      style={styles.style}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainerStyle}
      text1Style={styles.text1Style}
      text1NumberOfLines={2}
      text2Style={styles.text2Style}
      text2NumberOfLines={2}
    />
  ),
  error: (props) => (
    <ErrorToast
      {...props}
      style={[styles.style, styles.errorStyle]}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainerStyle}
      text1Style={styles.text1Style}
      text1NumberOfLines={2}
      text2Style={styles.text2Style}
      text2NumberOfLines={2}
    />
  ),
};
<Toast config={toastConfig} ref={(ref) => Toast.setRef(ref)} />
```

Check [this link](https://github.com/calintamas/react-native-toast-message/blob/main/docs/custom-layouts.md) for complete customization.

Answer (score 0):

Set `style.height="auto"` and `text2NumberOfLines=0`.

Effect:

[image]

This is how I style it in version `2.2.0`:

```
import React from "react";
import Toast, {
  BaseToast,
  BaseToastProps,
  ToastConfig,
} from "react-native-toast-message";

const toastProps: BaseToastProps = {
  text1Style: {
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  text2Style: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  text2NumberOfLines: 0,
  style: {
    height: "auto",
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 0,
  },
};

export const toastConfig: ToastConfig = {
  success: (props) => (
    <BaseToast
      {...props}
      {...toastProps}
      style={[
        toastProps.style,
        {
          borderLeftColor: "#69C779",
        },
      ]}
    />
  ),
  error: (props: BaseToastProps) => (
    <BaseToast
      {...props}
      {...toastProps}
      style={[
        toastProps.style,
        {
          borderLeftColor: "#FE6301",
        },
      ]}
    />
  ),
  warning: (props) => (
    <BaseToast
      {...props}
      {...toastProps}
      style={[
        toastProps.style,
        {
          borderLeftColor: "#FFC107",
        },
      ]}
    />
  ),
};

<Toast config={toastConfig} />
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `Toast.show` you can do this like:

```
  Toast.show({
    topOffset: 100,
    type: "error",
    text1: "ERROR",
    text2: `${data}`,
    visibilityTime: 500,
    props: {
      text1NumberOfLines: //number of how many lines you want
    }
  });
```

Of course you can change this prop `text1NumberOfLines` to `text2NumberOfLines`.

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: Not working for me either